# How to add two values that are in HTML code via php script?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Doing a project for school and I need a way to sum two values that are pulled from my database into HTML view file via PHP code.

So the code is:

```
<p id="suma_prihoda" value="<?php echo array_sum($DATA['suma_prihoda']); ?>">Total sum of income is: <b><?php echo array_sum($DATA['suma_prihoda']); ?></b> euros.</p>
<p id="suma_rashoda" value="<?php echo array_sum($DATA['suma_rashoda']); ?>">Total revenue sum is: <b><?php echo array_sum($DATA['suma_rashoda']); ?></b> euros.</p>
```

I tried using a script that get's the value of the paragraph from document.getElementById('suma_prihoda').value and tried to make variables that can subract the two values to get a total account balance and it didn't work.

Prior to this I made a Controller which get's all the cash entry(it's a money related Veb site) values into an array, and then used the 'array_sum' to add all of it. So at the end of that part of the assignment I have two values, one for my income, and one for my revenue. And I need to get the total balance.
I know it's easy to subtract 1400-1200 euros, but I need the program to do it itself.

the script I used (that didn't work) was:

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("suma_prihoda").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("suma_rashoda").value;

    var element = document.getElementById("xxx");
    element.innerHTML = x - y;
</script>
```

I am looking for some guidelines to what I could do in this (CMS Veb site), and I can provide more blocks of code if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's hard to tell what's going on, but assuming your PHP is working, are you parsing `x` and `y` to numbers before subtracting them?

Comment: "That didn't work" is always problematic. Can you give us more information? If there were console errors, what were they? Was the result different to what you expected? You seem to be attempting this using javascript, yet you question  title suggests you want to do this with PHP, which can be done fairly easily, and possibly would be better than using javascript.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the fast responses and a happy welcome. my PHP works fine, I will post a picture bellow @ggorlen.. basically I need these two numbes retracted one from another, to get a total ballance. Php would be better, I just tried javascript as my first option because it seemed more elegant to me. code  from the controller is too long to post, but I will post a image bellow. Here are 3 images in a imgur album, first image is: what the Web page looks like, Second is the block of code in my view index.php and the third is from my Controller. https://imgur.com/a/xW6owPN is the imgur alb.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can "**print**" directly the value into the variable:

```
<script>
    var x = <?php echo array_sum($DATA['suma_prihoda']); ?>;
    var y = <?php echo array_sum($DATA['suma_rashoda']); ?>

    var element = document.getElementById("xxx");
    element.innerHTML = x - y;
</script>
```

Comment: Just note, this won't work if used in an external script file.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I instantly rejected this option because I thought it's too easy and wouldn't work. Cheers 2 everyone. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Note `value` is not a valid attrbute for `<p>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes .

For Example:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("suma_prihoda").value;
var y = document.getElementById("suma_rashoda").value;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
var element = document.getElementById("xxx");
element.innerHTML = x - y;
```

```html
<p id="suma_prihoda" value="21">Total sum of income is: <b>21</b> euros.</p>
<p id="suma_rashoda" value="10">Total revenue sum is: <b>10</b> euros.</p>
<div id="xxx"></div>
```

What you actually want is a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("suma_prihoda").dataset.value;
var y = document.getElementById("suma_rashoda").dataset.value;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
var element = document.getElementById("xxx");
element.innerHTML = x - y;
```

```html
<p id="suma_prihoda" data-value="21">Total sum of income is: <b>21</b> euros.</p>
<p id="suma_rashoda" data-value="10">Total revenue sum is: <b>10</b> euros.</p>
<div id="xxx"></div>
```

Just replace my hard coded values with your PHP echo statements.

**PHP OPTION**

create some variables, do the math with those and echo the result:

```
<?php
$income = array_sum($DATA['suma_prihoda']);
$revenue = array_sum($DATA['suma_rashoda']);
$difference = $income - $revenue
?>
<p id="suma_prihoda" >Total sum of income is: <b><?php echo $income; ?></b> euros.</p>
<p id="suma_rashoda" >Total revenue sum is: <b><?php echo $revenue; ?></b> euros.</p>
<p>Difference: <b><?php echo $difference; ?></b></p>
```